# Как добавить в cmake собственную библиотеку из другого проекта

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cmake

У меня 2 проекта.
Первый - статическая библиотека с протоколом.
Второй - декстопный клиент, который использует эту библиотеку.

Как правильно я могу прописать эту библиотеку в cmake файл второго проекта?
к примеру библиотеки всегда подключал так:

```
target_link_libraries (${CLIENT_NAME}
    ${CONAN_LIBS_QT}
)
```

Я понимаю, что нужно будет добавить сюда эту библиотеку. Но как мне указать путь до моей библиотеки, чтобы проект ее использовал? (использую linux)

Comment: Разные библиотеки придется подключать совершенно по-разному. *"к примеру библиотеки всегда подключал так"* - удивительно

Comment: я имел ввиду через команду target_link_libraries. Другие способы мне неизвестны.

Comment: Обычно одним макросом target_link_libraries не обойтись. Ну и использование этого макроса тоже может очень сильно различаться в зависимости от библиотеки.

Comment: нет смысла прописывать про find_package, conan_basic_setup и прочее - т.к. они работают с крупными сторонними библиотеками. Моя же библиотека не подключается таким способом в другой проектом.и поэтому я не выкладываю полностью код cmake.

Comment: @KonstantinMorozov включаете проект с вашей либой в основной проект с помощью add_subdirectory и используете цель из проекта